# Creating a Quick Calculation with Dates that Repeat in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

So, I'm in PowerBI Desktop. I have a table that pulls in data for various properties (website A, website B, website C) and creates a row for each property, for each day. So, for example, it'd look like this over the course of three days.

A snapshot of the data:

[image: A snapshot of the data]

**I need to create a single measure, showing the total number of returning users (for all properties) month-to-date.**

My original plan was to do *Quick Measures > Time Intelligence > Month-to-date Total*.

The "Quick Measure" form I'm using:

[image: The "Quick Measure" form I'm using]

This creates this measure:

```
usersReturning MTD = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('dailyLog'[date]),
    TOTALMTD(SUM('dailyLog'[usersReturning]), 'dailyLog'[date].[Date])
)
```

However, when I try to make this value shown in a card tile, it just shows (blank). And in the past, I know at some point it creates another kind of error. (I'm having difficulty replicating the value.) I'm wondering if this is because I don't have unique dates, but repeating dates? But I'm not getting any feedback on why.

I'm relatively new to PowerBI, and particularly to the quick measures and DAX scripting. So open to help or suggestions, and wondering if there is a way to make this work with the data schema that I'm showing here.

Comment: Hello @bsebesta & welcome to StackOverflow. The dates will not affect the sum. See here for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63510929/14010152  Please be sure to click to accept the answer to show that the question has been resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this data...

[image]

You can use a `TABLE` visualization. **Don't** check date, & use `sum` on the **returning users** to get this report:

[image]

Your **"single measure"** is 7565, but you can also see a summary of A, B, & C to understand how that measure came to be. But if you really just want the 7565 all by itself, then select `Card` as the visual:

[image]

Comment: Joe, thanks for replying. Your solution works in providing a sum, which is definitely PART of what I'm after. I'm still uncertain how to get the **month-to-date sum**. If I have a lot more data, how do I just see a number that shows the last 30 days of returning users?

Comment: @bsebesta , If you had August (the current month right now) in the data source, then use the month filter & pick August. That returns the "month-to-date" summary. As a **BONUS QUESTION** you can view the last 30 days by using a `Top N` filter to show the top 30 days...